# how to get onclick event on the div inside the iframe using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

> HTML Structure

```
<iframe src="#" scrolling="no" id="gallery-frame">
<div class="gv_filmstrip">
<div class="gv_frame">
<div class="gv_thumbnail current">
<img src="images/grandstand-padang-right/1.jpg">
</div></div>
<div class="gv_frame">
<div class="gv_thumbnail">
<img src="images/grandstand-padang-right/2.jpg">
</div></div>
<div class="gv_frame">
<div class="gv_thumbnail">
<img src="images/grandstand-padang-right/3.jpg">
</div></div>
</div>
<div class="gv_panel"><img src="images/grandstand-padang-right/1.jpg"></div>
<div class="gv_panel"><img src="images/grandstand-padang-right/2.jpg"></div>
<div class="gv_panel"><img src="images/grandstand-padang-right/3.jpg"></div>
</iframe>
```

What i want is?
I want to access the class `gv_frame` and put a onclick event on it .. in onclick event i need to find the width and height of `img` in `gv_panel`

Scripts i tried..

```
$("#gallery-frame").contents().find("gv_frame").click(function(){
alert("aaa"); // I am not getting the alert
});
```

> 2nd try

```
var width = $(".gv_panel img").width();
    var height = $(".gv_panel img").height();
    alert("width:"+width+" and height :"+height); // alert is null here
```

Answer (score 0):

You have typos. Remove the `contents()` and add a `.` to your class selector.

```
$("#gallery-frame").find(".gv_frame").click(function(){
    alert("aaa"); // I am not getting the alert
});
```

Comment: I have tried that .. as the gv_frame and all are in iframe ..its not working somehow..